# Web API 2 URL routing 403/404 error on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, url-routing

I am implementing a RESTful web services host using ASP.Net 4.5 and Web Api 2 Attribute Routing.  I also included [Web Api Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages).  When I run it locally through Visual Studio 2012 on IIS Express it works great and looks really cool; it displays the default /home/index page with an API menu that shows the documentation for all my RESTful API functions.  I have also tested all the API methods with SOAPUI and running locally everything works perfectly.

But the URL routing absolutely refuses to work when deployed to IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 Server R2.

When I browse the site I get:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

If I try the /home/index or any of the routes of my web api methods I get:

404 - File or directory not found.

I have installed .Net 4.5 on the server and then went to Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 and ran:

Aspnet_regiis -i

iisreset

I deployed my app to IIS and set the Application Pool to use .Net Framework v4.0.30319 and Managed pipeline mode: Integrated.

I have the following settings in my web.config:

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

I have tried many different variations on the web.config entries.  For example, the suggestion in [this post](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) does not work either:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC e.g. FormsAuthentication, Roles etc. -->
</modules>
```

Nor does changing the Handlers section like this have any effect:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

I did try turning directory browsing on and then it showed the website contents just fine, so the 403 Forbidden error is because directory browsing was forbidden.

But I don't want to browse the contents, I want URL routing to work.  In RouteConfig.cs file I have a default route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

So if URL routing were working then it should show the Home/Index view by default.

I also tried adding an Index.html file to the site and that worked fine too.  So the website works fine as a website, but URL routing refuses to work.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have similar code and problems.

Comment: How it got resolved?Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute to < modules > tag in web.config

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
```